# Built-in List that can be accessed by index and key

Tags: c#, dictionary, list

Is it possible to create a list that can be access by either an index or a key?

*I am looking for a Collection type that already exists but has this facility, I want to avoid redefining the indexers*

Comment: Define Index and Key. Post the syntax you want to write.

Comment: When you say "create" are you looking to create a new type of Collection with this facility, or are you looking for a Collection type that already exists but has this facility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection can do this, but it can only store strings as values.

```
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection k = 
        new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

    k.Add("B", "Brown");
    k.Add("G", "Green");

    Console.WriteLine(k[0]);    // Writes Brown
    Console.WriteLine(k["G"]);  // Writes Green
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a similar question at [What is the best data structure in .NET for look-up by string key or numeric index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137753/what-is-the-best-data-structure-in-net-for-look-up-by-string-key-or-numeric-ind).

Have a look at [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx):

```
class IndexableDictionary<TKey, TItem> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
 { Dictionary<TItem, TKey> keys = new Dictionary<TItem, TKey>();

   protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item) { return keys[item];}

   public void Add(TKey key, TItem item) 
    { keys[item] = key;
      this.Add(item);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Existing answers already show how to add your own indexers.

You might want to look at some of the existing key-based collections, such as `SortedList<,>`, which acts similarly to `Dictionary<,>`, but allows key and position indexer usage.

Also - you should be able to use inheritance for much of this type of thing - for example, inheriting from `Collection<>` or `List<>`. Note that if your collection implements `IList`/`IList<T>`, I don't recommend the following (which I see occasionally):

```
public SomeType this[int someId] {...}
```

The point is, people expect the integer indexer of an `IList[<T>]` to be positional.

Answer (score 1):

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

As well as doing just an integer index, you can provide a key of any other type you like

```
public object this[String key]
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

If you don't want to define your own collection, just inherit from `List<T>`, or just use a variable of type `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an indexer by adding the following property to your collection:

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get { /* return the specified index here */ }
    set { /* set the specified index to value here */ }
}
```

This can be quickly added in Visual Studio by typing *indexer* and pressing [tab] [tab].

The return type and indexer type can be changed ofcourse. You can also add multiple indexer types.