# Data structure with key and value as class type and access value using both key and index

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, collections

I am looking for a data structure in C# similar to Dictionary where i can access value by using index and key.The value is of type Class and not string.

I am creating a class library where i am trying to create a method named `Item` which returns value from my value and key pair data structure. But if i pass integer parameter to `Item` then it should get value by using index and if pass string type to `Item` then it should access value by using key (as in Dictionary)

Note: i referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298281/built-in-list-that-can-be-accessed-by-index-and-key) link . But System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection cannot be used as it can only store strings as values, but i want class type as value. I want to access value using both key and index.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` ? `TValue` could be a base class.

Comment: @MaxSorin Sorry. I didn't get you. I want to access the value by using both key and index.

Comment: as above, Max is correct, using generics you can store a class as a value in a dictionary and then run linq queries against the value column of this Dictionary to filter out the results you require.

Comment: @Navaneeth are you looking for this: [Accessing a Dictionary.Keys Key through a numeric index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227/accessing-a-dictionary-keys-key-through-a-numeric-index)?

Comment: If performance is much more of a concern than memory (memory complexity of `O(2n)` instead of `O(n)` and time complexity of `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` for look-ups by value), then you could use two backing `Dictionary`s, one which maps each key to a value, and one which maps each value to its key. If multiple keys can hold the same values, the value-key dict will store a `HashSet` or `List` of keys instead. EDIT: Use a backing `TValue` array or list instead of the value-key dictionary if you just want to be able to access values by index.

Comment: I think you're looking for an [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132568(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @EvilTak : there is no such thing as O(2n) . O(2n) is exactly the same as O(n)! If you want to implement the data structure yourself, I think `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` + `List<TKey>` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: I know, @Falanwe, I thought that'd just make it clear that it'd use twice the space. I could have just said "it uses twice the space", I don't know why I didn't think of that then.

Answer (score 1):

If a non-generic collection suits your needs, you could use [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132568(v=vs.110).aspx). Expect to do a lot of boxing and unboxing if you work with value types though.

If you absolutely want a generic version, you will have to build your own. For instance:

```
public class OrderedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    private List<TKey> _keys = new List<TKey>();

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerDictionary[key];
        }

        set
        {
            if(!_innerDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _keys.Add(key);
            }
            _innerDictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public TValue this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerDictionary[_keys[index]];
        }

        set
        {
            _innerDictionary[_keys[index]] = value;
        }
    }        

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _innerDictionary.Add(key, value);
        _keys.Add(key);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerDictionary.Clear();
        _keys.Clear();
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        if (_innerDictionary.Remove(key))
        {
            _keys.Remove(key);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

You will probably need to had some more exception handling, but most of the features are here. Also, if you want to implement `IDictionary<TKey,TVale>` from there, the missing members should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKeyItem, TValueItem> myDictionary =
        new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKeyItem, TValueItem>();
    var key = new TKeyItem();   //create key object
    var val = new TValueItem(); //create value object
    myDictionary.Add(key, val); //add key value pair to the dictionary
    var valueByKey = myDictionary[key];  // it will return val by key
    var valuebyIndex = myDictionary.Values.ElementAt(0); // it will retun val by index
```

Comment: See the comment to Max Sorin's answer: never access a dictionary's value by index that way, the order is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Updated test to remove/add items to dictionary. It appears that removing and then adding a new item to the dictionary causes the new item to appear at the removed-item's position. Which makes my claim that *using a* `Dictionary` *for this task will work* **false**. I prefer to leave this answer in place. Even though it is not a valid solution it may demonstrate why the `Dictionary` solution should be not be used  when wanting to access the collection by key as well as index.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Common;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            var types = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(float), typeof(Guid), typeof(UnitTest1) };

            Dictionary <Guid, object> dictionary = types.Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x)).ToDictionary(y => Guid.NewGuid());

            types.ToList().ForEach(t =>
                Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.Any(x => x.Value.GetType() == t))
            );

            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(0).Value is int);
            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(1).Value is float);
            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(2).Value is Guid);
            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(3).Value is UnitTest1);

            dictionary.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());

            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(4).Value is Guid);

            //Remove the Guid
            dictionary.Remove(dictionary.ElementAt(2).Key);

            //See that the Element at the 2 position is now UnitTest1
            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(2).Value is UnitTest1);

            //See that the Element at the 1 position is still float
            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(1).Value is float);

            dictionary.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), new List<Guid>());

            //See that a newly added item is put the end of the dictionary
            Assert.IsTrue(dictionary.ElementAt(4).Value is List<Guid>); //This Assertion Fails. The List<Guid> appears at position 2.
        }
    }    
}
```

Code above creates a dictionary of objects of various types and then finds them in the dictionary based on the type. Lastly we get the dictionary element at the 0 position and assert that it is an `int`. Note that the key of the dictionary is not used, and could have been any datatype.

Comment: You should never use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` this way, because the order the enumerable retrieves the value is undefined. It's even explicitly mentionned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) : "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined."

Comment: You will notice that I'm using the extension method defined by an interface that `Dictionary<>` implements. I'm not using `.ToArray()[0]` to get the value at the 0 position. Additional `Assert` statements added to the answer will prove that the behavior is as expected. Though this does cause additional re-enumerations through the collection.

Comment: I do notice it, but that doesn't change anything. Nothing gives you the certitude you that `ElementAt(4)` is indeed the fifth element that was added to the dictionary. It appears to be the case on .Net 4.5.2 implementation (the one I'm running), but it's an undefined behaviour, an implementation detail you should never rely on.

Comment: So it would appear to me that the documentation is confusing on this point. One piece of it states that the `Enumerable` extension is implemented. However your quote indicates to the contrary, and is proven wrong by the passing unit tests in my answer.

Comment: Also notice that all hell breaks loose if you factor in deletion. Try this: `var myDict = new Dictionary<int,int>{{0,0}, {1,1},{2,2}}; myDict.Remove(0); myDict.Add(3,3); var mysteryResult = myDict.ElementAt(0).Value;` Without running it, what's the value of mysteryResult?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is well implemented, but the enumerable you get is just not in a particular order. The only certitude you have is that it contains all the key-value pairs contained in the dictionary.